# Fill matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, fill

I have a preallocated matrix in R  and need to fill it with data from a dataframe generated from a file having following format:

```
1-1-7  
1-3-2  
2-2-6  
1-4-8  
....
```

where the first column contains a row index, the second a column index, and the 3rd contains the values.

Is there a faster/better way then the following loop?

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(file)){  
    matrix[file[i,1],file[i,2]]=file[i,3]
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `row/col` index as the first and second columns of `file` and assign the `file[,3]` to `m1` using those index.

```
m1[as.matrix(file[1:2])] <- file[,3]
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    7    0    2    8
#[2,]    0    6    0    0
```

As I mentioned above, we assign the values based on the row/column index.  If we take the first two columns and convert to matrix, the first column acts as the row index and second as the column index

```
 as.matrix(file[1:2])
 #     v1 v2
 #[1,]  1  1
 #[2,]  1  3
 #[3,]  2  2
 #[4,]  1  4
```

If we subset the `m1` based on the first row i.e. `1 1`, we are getting the element of `m1` at row=1 and column=1, similarly for the 2nd row, it would be the element at row=1 and column=3, and so on..  Here, we created a matrix of `0` with the specified dimensions.  So, the 4 values based on the row/columns positions will be `0`

```
m1[as.matrix(file[1:2])]
#[1] 0 0 0 0
```

Now, we are changing/replacing the values in 'm1' at the specified row/column positions by assigning the value to the 3rd column of 'file'

```
 m1[as.matrix(file[1:2])] <- file[,3]
```

If we check the values at the specified position, it will be replaced

```
 m1[as.matrix(file[1:2])] 
 #[1] 7 2 6 8
```

---

Or we can use another approach using `sparseMatrix` from `library(Matrix)`

```
library(Matrix)
sM <- sparseMatrix(file[,1], file[,2], x=file[,3])
as.matrix(sM)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    7    0    2    8
#[2,]    0    6    0    0
```

#### data

```
file <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
v3 = c(7, 2, 6, 8)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

m1 <- matrix(0, nrow=max(file[,1]), ncol=max(file[,2]))
```

Comment: I really like the sparse matrix approach. That's essentially what they have there.

Comment: after setting the correct row/col names, the first approach works perfect. thank you!. can someone explain to me how it works? you take 2 entire vectors as an index of m1 and assign an entire vector to it?.. does r then "sort" the values automatically?.. (real newbie at r programming...)

Comment: @JanS I added some explanation in the post.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @JanS.  While akrun does provide a great explanation, I suggest you take a look at this chapter (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) in advanced R.  It is very helpful.

Comment: yes it helped, thank you. I understand it as some kind of an implicit loop.. i wonder why its so much faster..

Comment: Wow pretty good answer there, I have edited a bit to increase readability. Rollback if you think it's wrong. Cheers. :)